# Android App FC when it runs anything with a UI and sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, user-interface

```
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.totsp.androidexamples/com.totsp.androidexamples.TestDatabaseActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.totsp.androidexamples.TestDatabaseActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.totsp.androidexamples-2.apk]
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.totsp.androidexamples.TestDatabaseActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.totsp.androidexamples-2.apk]
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
10-05 04:41:51.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5986):     ... 11 more
```

I tried following this: http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742
And I get this error. Basically when it starts it just dies on me.

Anybody could please enlighten me on what might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare TestDatabaseActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Well, it was declared at the Project Wizard. Do I have to modify it or something?

Comment: Hmm I think it's worth a quick check. Take a look in the AndroidManifest.xml for your project and look for the text ".TestDatabaseActivity". If you changed the package in which the class resides then you will have to change the name attribute in the xml to ".packagename.TestDatabaseActivity"